# jQuery Progress animate to predefined width - Multiple Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I animate multiple div width using animate, when a div has already a width defined in the css of html.

For example. If I have `style="width:30%;"` in the html, and I want to animate that div from 0 to 30% how can I do it? And do that in multiple divs with the same class?

To animate a div that has no width defined, to a certain value, I know I can do it like this `$('div').animate({ width: 'value' }, milisecs);` but I don't want to set the width value on the JS and repeating this line multiple times.

I created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helionbc/F69ut/) that may help better understanding.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess I'm missing the point. I took your fiddle and changed the JS to .fullmult and all four of the div bars went to 80%. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: @TimSPQR No, what I wanted to achieve was to animate multiple divs with different %'s. I got the correct answer bellow from Rohan. But thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) like,

**HTML**

```
<p>Single</p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fill" data-width="80%">
        <span><b>Bar One</b></span>    
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<p>Multiple</p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fillmult" data-width="90%">
        <span><b>Bar 1</b></span>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fillmult" data-width="50%">
        <span><b>Bar 2</b></span>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fillmult" data-width="70%">
        <span><b>Bar 3</b></span>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="fillmult" data-width="20%">
        <span><b>Bar 4</b></span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.container > div').each(function(){ // you can use $('.fill, .fillmult').each
    var width=$(this).data('width');
    $(this).animate({ width: width }, 1500);
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/cr6km/)**

Comment: This. Thank your for the quick reply. I have a question tho, its easier to grab data() then width() ? Just wondering. Thank you again.

Comment: If you apply width in style, then your divs will take the width before animating so using data-attribute is a good option.